# How do I create a dummy variable in R based on a dataset's median?

Tags: r, dummy-variable

My data has a median of 60. I'd like to create a dummy variable where 1 = >60 and 0 = <60.

Comment: For you data (vector) `x`, do `as.integer(x > median(x))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use ifelse function.

```
a = 1:100

median = 60

ifelse(a >= median, 1, 0)
```

If you use data frame for this problem use dplyr(0.5.0) is more efficient.

```
a = data.frame(col1 = 1:100)



a %>% mutate(dummy = case_when(.$col1 >= 60 ~ 1,
                               .$col1 < 60 ~ 0))
```